# Binomial Distribution probability in python

Tags: python, probability

for this problem:

The ratio of boys to girls for babies born in Russia is 1.09:1 If there is one child born per birth, what proportion of Russian families with exactly 6 children will have at least 3 boys?
Write a program to compute the answer using the above parameters:
A single line containing the following values:

1.09 1

this is my program:

```
pp=str(input())
p1=float(pp[:pp.find(' ')])
p2=float(pp[pp.find(' ')+1:])
pf=0.0
pa=0.0
from math import factorial as f
def comb(n,r):
    return f(n) / f(r) / f(n-r)
for i1 in range(1,7):
    if i1>=3:
        pf=pf+(pow(p1,i1)+pow(p2,6-i1))*comb(6,i1)
    pa=pa+(pow(p1,i1)+pow(p2,6-i1))*comb(6,i1)
print("%.3f"%(pf/pa))
```

the answer Ive got is 0.688 where the correct answer is 0.696, whats the problem in my code?

Comment: What's the meaning of those variables? Also: did you take into account that families might have *0* male children? Your `for` loop starts at `1` so maybe that's causing the small error.

Comment: pa is total probability and pf is the goal probability, p1 is probability of boys and p2 is for girls, after fixing for start point now i am getting 0.679 still not correct.

Comment: The most glaring bug in your code, to me, is in the mathematics: 1.09 and 1 are not the probabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to calculate the probability:

```
from math import factorial as f
b, g = map(float, input().split())
p = b / (b+g)
def comb(n, r):
    return f(n) / (f(r) * f(n-r))
n = 6
sum(p**k * (1-p)**(n-k) * comb(n, k) for k in range(3, 7))
# 0.6957033161509107
```

Comment: Not for py3 (which is what I use), you are right if you are using py2.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Your input
pp=str(input())
p1=float(pp[:pp.find(' ')])
p2=float(pp[pp.find(' ')+1:])
pf=0.0
#This is the probability of boy
p = p1/(p1+p2)
from math import factorial as f
def comb(n,r):
    return f(n) / f(r) / f(n-r)

#You have to sum the probabilities of 3,4,5 or 6 boys
for i1 in range(3,7):
    #You were not using the right formula (it's a multiplication, not a sum)
    prob_i1 = pow(p,i1)*pow(1-p,6-i1)*comb(6,i1)
    pf += prob_i1
print("%.3f"%(pf))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed my own code problems: 0 for loop start instead of 1 and * instead of + in pf sum:

```
pp=str(input())
p1=float(pp[:pp.find(' ')])
p2=float(pp[pp.find(' ')+1:])
pf=0.0
pa=0.0
from math import factorial as f
def comb(n,r):
    return f(n) / f(r) / f(n-r)
for i1 in range(0,7):
    if i1>=3:
        pf=pf+(pow(p1,i1)*pow(p2,6-i1))*comb(6,i1)
    pa=pa+(pow(p1,i1)*pow(p2,6-i1))*comb(6,i1)
print("%.3f"%(pf/pa))
```

now the output is correct, but both answers are better than my way. sorry for my complex code, thanks for help.